# Plotting Histogram for all columns in a Data Frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to draw histograms for all of the columns in my data frame.
I imported `pyspark` and `matplotlib`. 
df is my data frame variable.
plt is `matplotlib.pyplot` variable

I was able to draw/plot histogram for individual column, like this:

```
bins, counts = df.select('ColumnName').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).histogram(20)
plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins=bins, weights=counts)
```

But when I try to plot it for all variables I am having issues. Here is the for loop I have so far:

```
for x in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    bins, counts = df.select(x).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).histogram(20)
    plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins=bins, weights=counts)
```

How would I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your loop is wrong- try: `for x in df.columns:`. If this doesn't work, please provide the error message.

Comment: @Parfait  df is created using  spark.read.csv("csv file",inferSchema=True,header=True)

Comment: @pault loop was wrong. Can you please add this as an answer, so I can accept?

Comment: @Parfait Apologies, my intention was to keep the code clean and point directly to where the issue was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `for` loop:

```python
for x in range(0, len(df.columns)):
```

Will iterate over a range of integers. Then when you try to access the column via:

```python
df.select(x)
```

You will get an error because `x` is not a valid column identifier.

Instead, change your loop to:

```python
for x in df.columns:
```

and the rest of your code will work.

Answer (score 32):

As an alternative to the `for` loop approach, I think you can try this:

```
df.hist(bins=30, figsize=(15, 10))
```

This will plot a histogram for each numerical attribute in the `df` DataFrame. Here, the `bins` and `figsize` arguments are just for customizing the output.

Comment: You are confusing the DataFrames from Pandas with those from PySpark. PySpark DataFrames do not have a `hist` method. Your answer may be relevant to Pandas though, but it's not for PySpark.